# PHP: Add div background color using decimal value (1= black and 0 = white)

Tags: javascript, php, html, css

So in my gaming system after I query the players database, I get a value between from 0 to 1. 0 should represent white and 1 should represent black. 0.01 to 0.99 represents the shades from white to black.

I use the gaming data to show the players profile details on a webpage.

How can I dynamically create a logic to generate the color code based on this decimal value? I need to make the background color of the div of each player a shade of grey as represented by the player's orientation number (0 to 1)

I tried to add `background-color:black` to the div and then reduce opacity to simulate change in shade. Unfortunately this also makes the content inside the div transparent too. I tried adding `opacity:1` to inside div but it did not work.

So I think finding a way to convert the decimal value to a hex value between black and white must be the way.

Any insight is greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 2):

The colors are expressed in RGB (Red, Green, Blue) with each value ranging between 0 and 255, so simply multiply your value by 255 for each color component and then set your div's background color like this:

```html
<div id="myDiv">This is a color test</div>

<script>
  var value = 0.1;
  var color_component = Math.ceil(255 * (1 - value));
  var color = "rgb(" + color_component + "," + color_component + "," + color_component + ")";
  document.getElementById("myDiv").style.backgroundColor = color;
</script>
```

Comment: He would need to do  `var color_comonent = 255 * (1 -  value)`. Not doing this would make values closer to zero darker and values closer to one lighter since 255 is the lightest possible value. This way, you the values are inverted.

Comment: Also, this would not give him a valid hex color. It could give him something like #255255255, which is not valid.

Comment: @Pavlin Thanks for the notes, fixed.

Answer (score 2):

Racil had the right idea, but constructed the color improperly. One way you could do it would be to calculate the color component like he suggested:

```
var color_component = 255 * (1 - value);
```

The you could use this to generate the color into something like this:

```
var color = 'rgb(' + value + ', ' + value + ', ' + value + ')';
```

Or if you wanted to be extra sneaky, you could convert this into a hexadecimal color by converting the color component to hexadecimal, like this:

```
var hex = new Number(color).toString(16);
var color = '#' + hex + hex + hex + ';';
```

Answer (score 1):

if you want use only PHP (better if the result beetween 0 and 1 come from PHP or database) I think this can be good way:

```
<?php
$res = 0.4; //that you have to put you result between 0 and 1
$rgb= intval($res*255);
$color = "rgb(".$rgb.", ".$rgb.", ".$rgb.")"; // the result of the code... for example "rgb(2, 2, 2)"
?>
```

then you have only to echo the color on your div style.